# Jquery append элемента с несколькими классами

Tags: jquery

Как через jquery создать элемент с несколькими классами?
Нужно получить что-то типа такого:

`<div class="firstclass secondclass thirdclass">Ou la la</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $element = $('<div class="firstclass secondclass thirdclass">Ou la la</div>');
$(".parent").append($element);
```